# What is the point of the Swipe feat?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

The 4th level Barbarian feat Swipe does not seem to give you anything above two normal Strikes:

> You make a wide, arcing swing. Make a single melee Strike and compare the attack roll result to the ACs of up to two foes, each of whom must be within your melee reach and adjacent to the other. Roll damage only once and apply it to each creature you hit. A Swipe counts as two attacks for your multiple attack penalty.
>   If you’re using a weapon with the sweep trait, its modifier applies to all your Swipe attacks.

For two actions, you get to attack two adjacent creatures, suffering the standard MAP. The only benefit I see that *if* you have a weapon with the Sweep property, you get to add it to both attacks.
Without a Sweep weapon, is this a wasted feat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You get to do two attacks using the same multiple attack penalty

If you spend your two first actions doing a sweep you have no multiple attack penalties (MAP) against two (adjacent) foes.

Alternately:
If you are confident enough with your rolling, you can use this as a second strike action to only apply a single multitude of MAP for two attacks.